# Change color in html list whenever mouseover items using addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html

I did this example about what is happening in my code, I'm not knowing how to change color when I pass mouse over items.

```js
document.querySelector('.item').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e){
    e.target.style.color = "red";
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item">1</li>
  <li class="item">2</li>
  <li class="item">3</li>
  <li class="item">4</li>
  <li class="item">5</li>
  <li class="item">6</li>
  <li class="item">7</li>
  <li class="item">8</li>
  <li class="item">9</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: come online, I just solved it for you.. in the future, for stuff like these, you can test the errors yourself, looking at console, seeing what functions that you didnt make actually return, stuff like that.. keep on learning :}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't as hard as you think it is.. the REAL problem is actually with what you are adding the event listener to.. you add the event listener to `document.querySelector('.item')` and all querySelector does is select the first element that pops up with that specification, therefore only the first element gets the event listener applied to it

Long story short, your code only applies to the first element(in your example at least). The solution is to use a method that applies your event listener to each element.

```js
var d=document.getElementsByClassName('item')
Object.keys(d).forEach(a=>{
  d[a].addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e){
    e.target.style.color = "red"
  })
})
/*
now i shall explain my logic
the function getElementsByClassName(classNameToString) returns an object and each key contains a different element
next, i made an array of the keys of the object(that was the whole Object.keys(objectName)) and forEach index(yea that's where the name comes from) in this array(remember this is an array of the object's keys) i read in the data of each index(which is a key; the parameter called 'a' right before the => sign)
now the data of each index is a key of the object, the object that contains all the elements that you want to an addEventListener to, therfore d[a] for each time in the loop would reference a different element, so by the time the loop is finished, all elements would've been referenced(in this case the eventListener is added to each element)
BUT
just in case you want to revert the color when your mouse leaves that element, i made the other part for you, that listens to the event 'mouseleave' instead(d is already declared)
*/
Object.keys(d).forEach(a=>{
  d[a].addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e){
    e.target.style.color = "black"
  })
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item">1</li>
  <li class="item">2</li>
  <li class="item">3</li>
  <li class="item">4</li>
  <li class="item">5</li>
  <li class="item">6</li>
  <li class="item">7</li>
  <li class="item">8</li>
  <li class="item">9</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use CSS:

```
li:hover{
  color:red;
}
```